# Lisp Executable

Tags: build, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I've just started learning Lisp and I can't figure out how to compile and link lisp code to an executable.

I'm using `clisp` and `clisp -c` produces two files:

- .fas
- .lib

What do I do next to get an executable?

Comment: You could use `compile-file` instead.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I was actually trying to do this today, and I found typing this into the CLisp REPL worked:

```
(EXT:SAVEINITMEM "executable.exe"
                 :QUIET t
                 :INIT-FUNCTION 'main
                 :EXECUTABLE t
                 :NORC t)
```

where main is the name of the function you want to call when the program launches, `:QUIET t` suppresses the startup banner, and `:EXECUTABLE t` makes a native executable.

It can also be useful to call

```
(EXT:EXIT)
```

at the end of your main function in order to stop the user from getting an interactive lisp prompt when the program is done.

EDIT: Reading the documentation, you may also want to add `:NORC t`
(read [link](http://clisp.cons.org/impnotes/image.html)). This suppresses loading the RC file (for example, `~/.clisprc.lisp`).

Comment: On ccl on mac os x 10.9 i am having a problem cretaing executables.
`(save-application "/full/path/to/saved-app" :prepend-kernel t)`
double clicking the produced executable file enters on terminal showing very long errors starting with a one like error: problems loadiing bundle:can't determine class name and ending with the kernel debugger options. On ccl on windows i simply define a function and do the same above to save executable, later i can double click the output file it runs and remembers my defined function, ccl on mac dont remember also when i save image and load it to kernel manually

Answer (score 36):

This is a [Lisp FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/lispfaq/) (slightly adapted):

> ***** How do I make an executable from my programme?**
>
> This depends on your implementation; you will need to consult your
>   vendor's documentation.
>
> - With ECL and GCL, the standard compilation process will
>      produce a native executable.
> - With LispWorks, see the *Delivery User's Guide* section of the
>      documentation.
> - With Allegro Common Lisp, see the *Delivery* section of the
>      manual.
> - etc...
>
> However, the classical way of interacting with Common Lisp programs
>     does not involve standalone executables. Let's consider this during
>     two phases of the development process: programming and delivery.
>
> *Programming phase*: Common Lisp development has more of an
>     incremental feel than is common in batch-oriented languages, where an
>     edit-compile-link cycle is common. A CL developer will run simple
>     tests and transient interactions with the environment at the
>     REPL (or Read-Eval-Print-Loop, also known as the
>     *listener*). Source code is saved in files, and the build/load
>     dependencies between source files are recorded in a system-description
>     facility such as ASDF (which plays a similar role to *make* in
>     edit-compile-link systems). The system-description facility provides
>     commands for building a system (and only recompiling files whose
>     dependencies have changed since the last build), and for loading a
>     system into memory.
>
> Most Common Lisp implementations also provide a "save-world" mechanism
>     that makes it possible to save a snapshot of the current lisp image,
>     in a form which can later be restarted. A Common Lisp environment
>     generally consists of a relatively small executable runtime, and a
>     larger image file that contains the state of the lisp world. A common
>     use of this facility is to dump a customized image containing all the
>     build tools and libraries that are used on a given project, in order
>     to reduce startup time. For instance, this facility is available under
>     the name EXT:SAVE-LISP in CMUCL, SB-EXT:SAVE-LISP-AND-DIE in
>     SBCL, EXT:SAVEINITMEM in CLISP, and CCL:SAVE-APPLICATION in
>     OpenMCL. Most of these implementations can prepend the runtime to the
>     image, thereby making it executable.
>
> *Application delivery*: rather than generating a single executable
>     file for an application, Lisp developers generally save an image
>     containing their application, and deliver it to clients together with
>     the runtime and possibly a shell-script wrapper that invokes the
>     runtime with the application image. On Windows platforms this can be
>     hidden from the user by using a click-o-matic InstallShield type tool.

Answer (score 14):

Take a look at the the official clisp homepage. There is a FAQ that answers this question.

http://clisp.cons.org/impnotes/faq.html#faq-exec

Answer (score 14):

CLiki has a good answer as well: [Creating Executables](http://www.cliki.net/Creating%20Executables)

Answer (score 3):

For a portable way to do this, I recommend [roswell](https://github.com/snmsts/roswell).

For any supported implementation you can create lisp scripts to run the program that can be run in a portable way by `ros` which can be used in a hash-bang line similarly to say a python or ruby program.

For SBCL and CCL roswell can also create binary executables with `ros dump executable`.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question but the Lisp code I'm looking at is 25 years old :-)

I could not get compilation working with clisp on Windows 10.
However, it worked for me with [gcl](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/novak/gclwin.html).

If my lisp file is jugs2.lisp,

```
gcl -compile jugs2.lisp
```

This produces the file jugs2.o if jugs2.lisp file has no errors.

Run gcl with no parameters to launch the lisp interpreter:

```
gcl
```

Load the .o file:

```
(load "jugs2.o")
```

To create an EXE:

```
(si:save-system "jugs2")
```

When the EXE is run it needs the DLL `oncrpc.dll`; this is in the `<gcl install folder>\lib\gcl-2.6.1\unixport` folder that gcl.bat creates.

When run it shows a lisp environment, call (main) to run the main function
(main).