# Common Lisp equivalent to Haskell's main function?

Tags: scripting, haskell, common-lisp, program-entry-point

Haskell's `main` function does just what I want: evaluate when the file is loaded by itself (e.g. `./myfile.hs` or `runhaskell myfile.hs`) and in no other case. `main` will not be called when the file is imported by another file. [newLISP](http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/mcandre/newlisp/module.lsp) also has this functionality.

Is there equivalent code for Common Lisp?

I read the [source code](http://clisp.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/clisp/clisp/src/spvw.d?view=markup) for CLISP. Here's what happens when the user enters `clisp myfile.lisp` or `./myfile.lisp`:

1. CLISP saves `myfile.lisp` as `p->argv_execute_file`.
2. CLISP creates the expression `(LOAD "p->argv_execute_file")` and pushes it onto the Lisp stack.
3. CLISP saves any additional command-line arguments in a list.
4. CLISP stores the arguments in the Lisp variable `*args*`.

CLISP never makes a Lisp variable referring to `p->argv_execute_file`, so there is no way to discern whether `myfile.lisp` was loaded directly, by the user in the REPL, or by another Lisp file. If only `(car *args*)` were `myfile.lisp`, my task would be easy.

Note: Shebangs give CLISP trouble if the file is loaded from the REPL, so I put this code in `~/.clisprc.lisp`:

```
(set-dispatch-macro-character #\# #\!
 (lambda (stream character n)
  (declare (ignore character n))
  (read-line stream nil nil t)
  nil))
```

Comment: Why do you need an equivalent to the main function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [solution](https://github.com/mcandre/mcandre/blob/master/cl/hello.lisp). It's a bit of shell trickery, but it works. I'll soon modify this to work on CL implementations other than CLISP.

```
#!/bin/sh
#|
exec clisp -q -q $0 $0 ${1+"$@"}
exit
|#

;;; Usage: ./scriptedmain.lisp

(defun main (args)
 (format t "Hello World!~%")
 (quit))

;;; With help from Francois-Rene Rideau
;;; http://tinyurl.com/cli-args
(let ((args
       #+clisp ext:*args*
       #+sbcl sb-ext:*posix-argv*
       #+clozure (ccl::command-line-arguments)
       #+gcl si:*command-args*
       #+ecl (loop for i from 0 below (si:argc) collect (si:argv i))
       #+cmu extensions:*command-line-strings*
       #+allegro (sys:command-line-arguments)
       #+lispworks sys:*line-arguments-list*
     ))

  (if (member (pathname-name *load-truename*)
              args
              :test #'(lambda (x y) (search x y :test #'equalp)))
    (main args)))
```

Comment: The `exit` in line 4 is not necessary — due to `exec`, shell will never run it. And CL ignores it anyway. So line 4 can be removed

Answer (score 0):

<del>`(eval-when (situation*) ...)`</del>

**Update** sorry for the confusing answer.

I could be wrong, but it seems to be impossible to do what you want exactly. I would make a shell script and call `clisp -i myfile.lisp -x (main)`.

Is there any reason to not make it executable (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046/lisp-executable))?

P.S. Common Lisp is a language and `clisp` is one of the implementations.

Comment: :load-toplevel only works while the code is compiling and :execute calls main whenever the file is loaded, not quite the desired functionality.

Comment: @mcandre `:load-toplevel` works when the file is loaded, but everything else is correct, I'm going to update the answer, thanks.

Comment: clisp -i myscript.cl wouldn't work well as a shebang. Also, clisp doesn't allow -x arguments when loading a script. But thanks anyway :)