# How to write a clisp executable file?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lisp Executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046/lisp-executable)

Was getting started with Clisp and the biggest problem I faced is that there are very few tutorials out there to explain how to write clisp files. Most of the tutorials are about using it in command line.

I'm not using Emacs. I'm using Clisp + Sublime on Ubuntu. Thus, what should I do to write a file of lisp code and execute it.

Answer (score 3):

See the CLISP documentation how to save an executable:

http://clisp.org/impnotes/image.html

Answer (score 0):

The most common way is to load your file using Slime. I strongly suggest you start using it.

If you absolutely don't want to, you can, as [Clisp documentation states](http://www.gnu.org/software/clisp/impnotes/clisp.html#opt-exec-file), use the `--lisp-file` option.

Comment: It's great that you think that a tool is good, but he said he's not using emacs, why try to make him?

Comment: Because that's what everybody uses. Would you go on the web and use exclusively lynx? Everybody uses full web browsers, good luck debugging without one. The analogy may not be perfect, but you get the idea.

Comment: The analogy sucks.  I took the time and trouble to learn Emacs, but it's perfectly reasonable to want to do something else.